# How to determine the position of a planet in our solar system?

Tags: orbital-motion, planets, space, orbitals

I am trying to modelize our galaxy with a simple program.

I know how to find the period speed and acceleration of a satellite but I don't know how to get the angle and the current distance between the satelite and the object it is orbiting.

Comment: The whole universe, eh?  Have you read The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy?